# How to get start offset and end offset of a search string in search result in elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have a requirement to find the start and end position of a particular word in a text.

Suppose my text is "The patient date of birth is 12/11/2019", and I am searching for "date of birth" in the text. Upon search I need to get start and end offset of the search string in the search result.  Is it possible using elasticsearch?

What I have tried so far,

**Created index:**

```
PUT /medicalrecord
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Name": "text",
      "Text":  { "type": "text", "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"  }
    }
  }
}
```

**Input text**

```
POST /medicalrecord/_doc
{
  "Name": "medicalrecord 1",
  "Text" : "The patient date of birth is 12/11/2019"
}
```

**Below API gives back the begin and end position of all the words present in the document**

```
GET /medicalrecord/_termvectors/[id]
{
  "fields" : ["Text"],
  "offsets" : true,
  "positions" : true,
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}
```

***Result->***

```
{
  "_index" : "medicalrecord",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "r0NhCXYBD643sv6Ogz-n",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "took" : 0,
  "term_vectors" : {
    "Text" : {
      "field_statistics" : {
        "sum_doc_freq" : 9,
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "sum_ttf" : 9
      },
      "terms" : {
        "11" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 7,
              "start_offset" : 32,
              "end_offset" : 34
            }
          ]
        },
        "12" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 6,
              "start_offset" : 29,
              "end_offset" : 31
            }
          ]
        },
        "2019" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 8,
              "start_offset" : 35,
              "end_offset" : 39
            }
          ]
        },
        "birth" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 4,
              "start_offset" : 20,
              "end_offset" : 25
            }
          ]
        },
        "date" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 2,
              "start_offset" : 12,
              "end_offset" : 16
            }
          ]
        },
        "is" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 5,
              "start_offset" : 26,
              "end_offset" : 28
            }
          ]
        },
        "of" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 3,
              "start_offset" : 17,
              "end_offset" : 19
            }
          ]
        },
        "patient" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 1,
              "start_offset" : 4,
              "end_offset" : 11
            }
          ]
        },
        "the" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 0,
              "start_offset" : 0,
              "end_offset" : 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Like the above operation, upon search of "date of birth", can I get the result as,

```
       "date of birth" : {
         "start_offset" : 12,
              "end_offset" : 25
        }
```

If we have multiple occurrences, add that too in the result.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a need for this as well; hoping someone might have ideas?